algotrading - discrepancies between model prevision and signals
As you can see below, although the model predictions closely follow the actual price trends, the trading strategy yields poor returns. This suggests that while the model captures the price direction, the thresholds for trading signals or the use of technical indicators may not align well with profitable trading behavior. This discrepancy could stem from overly cautious signal logic or limitations in model accuracy for price shifts significant enough to generate returns
returns: https://ibb.co/c2sHVxs
model predictions: https://ibb.co/3ygtGFL
Any suggestion on where I am mistaking?
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator
from ta.trend import MACD
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from ib_insync import IB, Stock, util

def download_data_ib(ticker, duration="5 Y", bar_size="1 day"):
    """
    Function to connect to IB and download historical data.
    """
    ib = IB()
    ib.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, clientId=100)

    contract = Stock(ticker, "SMART", "USD")
    bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
        contract,
        endDateTime="",
        durationStr=duration,
        barSizeSetting=bar_size,
        whatToShow="TRADES",
        useRTH=False
    )

    ib.disconnect()

    if not bars:
        raise ValueError(f"No data found for {ticker}")

    df = util.df(bars)
    df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
    return df[["close"]]

def prepare_data(data, lookback=20, split_ratio=0.8):
    """
    Function to prepare data for the LSTM model by normalizing it and creating 
    training and testing sets based on a lookback window.
    """
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(lookback, len(scaled_data)):
        X.append(scaled_data[i - lookback:i, 0])
        y.append(scaled_data[i, 0])

    X, y = np.array(X), np.array(y)
    X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))

    split = int(len(X) * split_ratio)
    X_train, X_test = X[:split], X[split:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:split], y[split:]

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, scaler

def create_model(input_shape, units=128, dropout_rate=0.2, learning_rate=0.001):
    """
    Function to create and compile an LSTM model for time series forecasting.
    """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(LSTM(units=units, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss="mean_squared_error")
    return model

def calculate_indicators(data):
    """
    Function to calculate technical indicators like RSI and MACD for the dataset.
    """
    data['RSI'] = RSIIndicator(close=data['close'], window=14).rsi()
    macd = MACD(close=data['close'], window_slow=26, window_fast=12, window_sign=9)
    data['MACD'] = macd.macd()
    data['Signal_Line'] = macd.macd_signal()
    return data

def backtesting_optimized(prices, y_pred, data):
    """
    Optimized backtesting function incorporating technical indicators and 
    calculating signals for buy/sell/hold decisions.
    """
    # Align prices and predictions
    prices = prices[-len(y_pred):]
    data = data[-len(y_pred):]

    # Generate optimized signals based on technical indicators and predictions
    signals = []
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        rsi = data.iloc[i]['RSI']
        macd = data.iloc[i]['MACD']
        signal_line = data.iloc[i]['Signal_Line']

        # Trading signal logic
        if (y_pred[i] > prices[i] * 1.02 and rsi < 70 and macd > signal_line):
            signals.append(1)  # Buy
        elif (y_pred[i] < prices[i] * 0.98 and rsi > 30 and macd < signal_line):
            signals.append(-1)  # Sell
        else:
            signals.append(0)  # Hold

    # Convert signals to numpy array for calculations
    signals = np.array(signals)

    # Calculate returns
    returns = np.diff(prices) / prices[:-1]
    signals = signals[:-1]  # Align signals and returns sizes
    strategy_returns = signals * returns

    # Calculate cumulative returns
    cumulative_strategy = np.cumsum(strategy_returns)
    cumulative_benchmark = np.cumsum(returns)

    # Plot cumulative returns
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(cumulative_strategy, label="Strategy (%)")
    plt.plot(cumulative_benchmark, label="Benchmark (%)")
    plt.title("Cumulative Returns: Strategy vs. Benchmark")
    plt.xlabel("Period")
    plt.ylabel("Cumulative Return (%)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return cumulative_strategy, cumulative_benchmark

def plot_predictions_vs_real(prices, predictions):
    """
    Plot model predictions vs. real prices.

    Parameters:
    - prices: Array or list of real prices.
    - predictions: Array or list of model predictions.
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(prices, label="Real Prices", linestyle="-", color="blue")
    plt.plot(predictions, label="Model Predictions", linestyle="--", color="orange")
    plt.title("Real Prices vs. Model Predictions")
    plt.xlabel("Period")
    plt.ylabel("Price")
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

# Main script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ticker = "NVDA"

    # 1. Download data
    data = download_data_ib(ticker)
    data = calculate_indicators(data)
    prices = data["close"].values

    # 2. Prepare data
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, scaler = prepare_data(data[['close']].values)

    # 3. Create and train model with default hyperparameters
    model = create_model(
        input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1),
        units=64,
        dropout_rate=0.2,
        learning_rate=0.001
    )
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

    # 4. Generate predictions and rescale
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test).flatten()
    y_pred_descaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

    # 5. Optimized backtesting
    cumulative_strategy, cumulative_benchmark = backtesting_optimized(prices, y_pred_descaled, data)

    # Plot predictions vs. real prices
    plot_predictions_vs_real(prices[-len(y_pred_descaled):], y_pred_descaled)


Your second chart is a little misleading, you compare the predicted price to the actual price, and visually they are close. But the object of the game is to predict price changes (returns) not price levels, that is what matters. You can be roughly right on price, sometimes a little high, sometimes a little low and yet make no money at all.

What works well in-sample doesn’t always work out-of-sample. In your case, how is your prediction different from a moving average? What logic does your "model" use to "predict" the next day’s value? Do you think a neural network can create a reliable out-of-sample strategy just by (over)fitting to one realization of the underlying process?

have a look at this question, might be helpful.
